# Angular momentum cylindrical coördinates

Tags: classical-mechanics

From "Classical Mechanics" - Taylor, problem 3.30

> Consider a rigid body rotating with angular velocity $\omega$ about a fixed axix. (You could think of a door rotating about the axis defined by its hinges.) Take the axis of rotation to be the z-axis and use cylindrical coordinates, $\rho_\alpha, \phi_\alpha, z_\alpha$ to specify the positions of the particles $\alpha = 1, \ldots, N$ that make up the body.
>
> **a.** Show that the velocity  of the particle $\alpha$ is $\rho_\alpha \omega$ in the $\phi$ direction.
>
> **b.** Hence show that the $z$ component of the angular momentum $l_\alpha$ of particle $\alpha$ is $m_\alpha\rho_\alpha^2\omega$.

I tried solving this as follows:

1. $\mathbf{v}=\boldsymbol{\omega}\times \mathbf{r}_\alpha$ with $\mathbf{r}_\alpha = (\rho_\alpha, \phi_\alpha, z_\alpha)$. And if I calculate this cross-product $(0,0,\omega)\times (\rho_\alpha, \phi_\alpha, z_\alpha)$ I get $(-\phi_\alpha \omega, \rho_\alpha \omega, 0)$. Which confirms problem part a.
2. I perform the same operation $\mathbf{l}_\alpha = \mathbf{r}_\alpha \times \mathbf{p}_\alpha = m\cdot \mathbf{r}_\alpha \times \mathbf{v}_\alpha$ using the $\mathbf{v}_\alpha$ I calculated above. The result is $$\mathbf{l}_\alpha = m(-\rho_\alpha z_\alpha \omega, \phi_\alpha z_\alpha \omega, \rho_\alpha^2 \omega + \phi_\alpha^2 \omega)$$
   But this does not agree with the suggested solution. Where am I wrong?

Comment: $\vec{r}_\alpha$ is not equal to $(\rho_\alpha,\phi_\alpha,z_\alpha)$ rather it is equal to $(\rho_\alpha,0,z_\alpha)$. This is common mistake when using curvilinear basis vectors.

Comment: The way $\phi$ comes into the picture for $\vec{r}$ is by determining the direction of $\hat{\rho}$.

Comment: Offcourse! silly mistake! Thank you

Comment: No problem :)! Been there myself.